# How to choose C# solution file in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, if I open a folder hierarchy that contains multiple C# solutions, sometimes I have very spotty formatting and intellisense functionality (formatting doesn't respect my .editorconfig file, I can't go to definition for methods, etc.).

The other day I noticed that I had a notification visible prompting me to select a solution file - once I did this, I had a better experience.
[image]

Clicking that lets me then pick one of the .sln files it found:
[image]

**However, this notification doesn't always appear, and I haven't been able to find out how to initiate this on demand.** When I search for the keywords like "choose" or "solution" in the command palette, I'm getting nothing useful. Is there a command to initiate this?

Comment: A sln is a solution file so the prompt only occurs when more than one sln file is found.

Comment: Are the .sln file all contained into seperate directories? if so, use your cmd line/terminal move into the target solution with `cd TargetSolutionDir` then simply `dotnet run` or whatever cmds you need. As far as I know, the dotnet cmd will act on purely that directory

Comment: I can reliably force this dialog by closing and reopening VS Code. Don't think they implemented a pallet command for this unfortunately.

Comment: It's definitely coming from the C# extension (ms-dotnettools.csharp) though. So maybe you can create an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp

Comment: You should also look into the [--project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run) flag for dotnet run cmd as well. To be honest its much simpler to keep one solution open at a time but you have some options through use of the terminal

Comment: Ha, there is one! Internally the command is called `dotnet.openSolution`. So try opening the command palette and enter "open" or "solution". That opens the solution selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "open" or "solution" in the command palette ([Ctrl]+[Shift]+[P]):

[image]

This will give you:

[image]

Comment: I think this must be the answer - although it's unintuitive since I already had the solution open, it does bring up the same second "select solution file" dialog that the notification does. Thanks!

Comment: You can also right-click on the .sln file and choose 'Open solution'.
However, on VS-Code for Mac, both options did NOT open the Solution Explorer in the Sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Add a file .vscode\settings.json with the contents:

`{
"dotnet.defaultSolution": "your-solution-name-here.sln"
}`

If you can put each *.sln file in a different subdirectory, then you can open each subdirectory in a different VS Code window and each will have its own intellisense and its own files subdirectory\.vscode\tasks.json and launch.json